# SlidingDrawer using a 9 patch handle image

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

How do I achieve the following?

[image: Expected][image: Actual]

The first image shows the result I want to achieve. The second one is the current result I'm getting from my layout. **Note** The image I'm using is the one from *android 1.6* jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content">

 <ImageView
     android:id="@id/handle"
     android:src="@drawable/drawer_handle"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

 <Button
    android:id="@id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
 </SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You may want to examine your activity in `hierarchyviewer` to see if the rules are being properly applied and what is holding onto the `ImageView`. I am a bit uncertain what the "parent" is for the `ImageView`, in terms of how `fill_parent` is going to be interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, used the **draw9patch** tool and set the image width to the horizontal size of the screen.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ended up hardcoding the horizontal width into the screen, but I was able to force the 9 patch to stretch horizontally by setting the layout_width to fill_parent and scaleType to fitXY (which is more generic for screen sizes)